# the subquery must return only one column and it returns 3

Tags: sql

Executing the following function

```
SELECT
  du.id AS "id_unit",
  du.sdes AS "PLACA",
  da.model AS "MODELO",
   
   (SELECT *  FROM tlm.main (
    du.id, 
    '2022-10-10', 
    '2022-10-11'
    )), 
  
   st.sdes AS "ESTADO DE OPERACIÓN"
  
FROM dat.unit du

LEFT OUTER JOIN esc.cstat csts ON du.id = csts.id_unit
LEFT OUTER JOIN esc.stat st ON csts.id_stat = st.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.model_units da ON du.id = da.id_unit
```

I get this console output:

> ERROR:  subquery must return only one column LINE 6:    (SELECT *
> FROM tlm.main (

the problem is that the tlm.main function has 3 columns and if I bring the 3 columns separately it is to execute the function 3 times, generating 3 times the processing time. Is there anything I can do?

If I make a left join:

```
SELECT
  du.id AS "id_unit",
  du.sdes AS "PLACA",
  da.model AS "MODELO",
  
  
   st.sdes AS "ESTADO DE OPERACIÓN"
  
FROM dat.unit du

LEFT JOIN  tlm.main_dash_tele_freq_blackout (
    du.id, 
    '2022-10-10', 
    '2022-10-11'
    )

LEFT OUTER JOIN esc.cstat csts ON du.id = csts.id_unit
LEFT OUTER JOIN esc.stat st ON csts.id_stat = st.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.model_units da ON du.id = da.id_unit
```

I get:

**ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 19: LEFT OUTER JOIN public.model_units da ON du.id = da.id_unit**

Comment: LEFT JOIN the subquery instead.

Comment: thanks. I edit the question including the left join